# Camerax failing to get supported resolutions

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm using CameraX to build a camera with with the Preview and Analysis use cases. I've built and run my application locally on an emulator and device. However after I publish to google play I'm getting the following stacktrace reported by crashlytics for one of my users:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not get supported output size under supported maximum for the format: 34
       at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.SupportedSurfaceCombination.checkSupported(SupportedSurfaceCombination.java)
       at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.SupportedSurfaceCombination.checkSupported(SupportedSurfaceCombination.java)
       at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.getMaxOutputSize(Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.java)
       at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.calculateSuggestedResolutions(CameraX.java)
       at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.attach(CameraX.java)
       at com.glan.input.fragment.CameraFragment.startCamera(CameraFragment.java) // *** Note this is where I call CameraX.bindToLifecycle(activity, previewUseCase, analysisUseCase)
       at com.glan.input.fragment.CameraFragment.access$000(CameraFragment.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onActivityCreated(Fragment.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchPause(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.allocBackStackIndex(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.completeShowHideFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I've looked through the source code for CameraX and what I found is that this error is thrown when none image output size candidates match a given the use case of and image format combo. `34` (the final characters of the error message) is the `PRIVATE` [image format](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#PRIVATE).

I've gone through the source code for both of the use cases that I'm using and it seems that the only formats which can possibly be selected are `YUV_420_888` (Preview and Analysis) or `JPEG` (Analysis).

It's certainly possible I missed something while reading the CameraX code. What can I do to ensure that the `PRIVATE` image format is never used?

For what it's worth, here's the device information of the device which saw this crash:

```
Device
Brand: LGE
Model: Nexus 5X
Orientation: Portrait
RAM free: 3.11 GB
Disk free: 554.61 MB

Operating System
Version: 6.0.1
Orientation: Portrait
Rooted: Yes
```

Comment: I'm seeing this same crash. Interestingly, it is also from a nexus 5X running Android 6.0.1 and Rooted=Yes. Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: unfortunately I haven't. I was on alpha6 (I think) when I got that, newer version of the library might have fixed the problem.